# Unable to access method defined in child class from parent class's #inherited method (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

What I'm trying to do:

```
class GrandFoo
    def self.inherited(subclass)
        puts subclass.new.respond_to? :bar  #false
    end
end

class Foo < GrandFoo
    def bar
        puts 'bar'
    end
end

# but
puts Foo.new.respond_to? :bar  #true
```

I was unable to find info about this case and actually I'm not sure what should I look for.
The goal is to "require" a list of files found in specific directory each containing a subclass with the same 'bar' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for `Class#inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited) says:

> Callback invoked whenever a subclass of the current class is created.

It says **is created**, not **has been created**. Presumably, this means that there are no guarantees as to how "complete" the class is, only that is *in the process* of being created.